# Division using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I am pretty sure that this must be some glaringly stupid mistake by me. But can anyone explain what is wrong in this division code using recursion. I know there are a lot of alternatives, but I need to know what is wrong with this

```py
def division(a, b):
    x = 0
    if a < b:
        return x
    else:
        x += 1
        return division(a - b, b) 
    return x
```

When I do `division(10, 2)`, it gives me 0 as output

Comment: In this case x has to be global.

Comment: You always set x to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always set your local variable `x` to `0`.

Then if the dividend is smaller than the divisor you return that `x` which is of course 0.

On the other hand when the dividend is greater or equal to the divisor you increment `x` by `1` and do a recursive call with a decremented dividend which will of course lead to the first case at the end and still you return an `x` which holds the value of `0`.

Note: Nonetheless your final `return` is not reachable since both your `if` and `else` branch contains a `return`.

So please try considering this solution:

```
def division(a, b):
    if a < b:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + division(a-b, b)
```

### Update:

A possible solution for working with negative integers following python's round towards negative infinity division:

```py
def division_with_negatives(a, b):
    a_abs, b_abs = abs(a), abs(b)
    if (a >= 0 and b >= 0) or (a < 0 and b < 0):
        # branch for positive results
        if a_abs < b_abs:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1 + division_with_negatives(a_abs - b_abs, b_abs)
    else:
        # branch for negative results
        if b_abs > a_abs or a_abs == b_abs:
            return -1
        else:
            return -1 + division_with_negatives(a_abs - b_abs, -b_abs)


assert division_with_negatives(-4, 1) == -4 // 1
assert division_with_negatives(10, 2) == 10 // 2
assert division_with_negatives(1, -5) == 1 // -5
assert division_with_negatives(-3, -2) == -3 // -2
```

Comment: What about negative values?

Comment: @AbbasEbadian updated the post with a possible solution for negative values

Answer (score -1):

This might save you from RecursionError:

```
def div(x, y):
if y == 0: 
    return 0
elif x == y:
    return 1
elif x < y:
    if y * -1 == x:
        return -1
    elif x % y == 0:
        return 1 + div(x - y, y)
    else:
        return 0
else: 
    if y < 0:
        return 1 - div(x - y, -y)
    else:
        return 1 + div(x - y, y)

#Application    
A = div(1, 2)
B = div(-9, 9)
C = div(3, 2)
D = div(-9, -3)
E = div(100, -2)
print(A)  # 0
print(B)  # -1
print(C)  # 1
print(D)  # 3
print(E)  # -50
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. OP ask specifically *... I need to know what is wrong with this <OP's code>...*; thus OP is looking for ***an explanation*** what he is doing wrongly in his code – he is not looking for code alternatives. He also does not have a recursion error; so motivating this answer with *This might save you from RecursionError:* seems weird. Apart from that your code as it is here results in an `IndentationError`. – Please revise your answer to include an explanation on what OP needs to fix in his code and why.

Answer (score -2):

Your escape condition is `if a < b`. That means that for this function to terminate, this must be fulfilled to leave the recursion. However, because `x` is declared at the top of the function, only redefined inside the body of the `else` statement but never returned, the function will always terminate with a value of `x = 0`.

You should either set `x = 1 + division(a-b,b)` or `return division(a-b,b) + 1` and remove the unreachable `return`at the end.

```
def div(a, b, x):
    if a < b:
        return x
    else:
        x +=1
        return div(a - b, b, x)

print(div(130, 10, 0))

# 13
```

Comment: So should I have to declare x global or is there any alternative?

Comment: Feed x back to itself --  this requires feeding in a 0 as x, which is inelegant but works: see my edits above

Answer (score -2):

This might work a little better for you:

```
def division(a,b,x=0):
    if a < b:
        return x
    else:
        x += 1
        return division(a-b,b,x) 
    return x
```

Every time your function ran through a new recusion, you were setting x to 0.  This way, it defaults to 0 if x is not specified, and should work like I *think* you want.

Also note that this will not work for negative numbers, but you probably knew that  :)

Comment: Unnecessary `return x` at the end, it is unreachable because of the preceding `if/else` block. Also the auxiliary `x` argument is completely unnecessary for this function. Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46031051/6337523) for a straightforward solution.

Answer (score -2):

With global you get:

```
def division(a,b):
    global x
    if a < b: return x
    else:
        x += 1
        return division(a-b,b) 

x=0  
print (division(10,2))
```

But you have to set `x` to zero every time before call the `division`

Answer (score -3):

i think this is best way, this way u can get floating answer also

```py
def division(a,b):
    if a == 0 or a == 1 or a == 2:
       return b
    else:
       return a / division(a % b,b) 
print(division(9,2))
```

Comment: please specify more you answer